# How a bitbucket pipeline knows the previous step is over an it's time to start the next one?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

There are multiple steps in pipelines and even multiple instructions inside a step, e.g.

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      script: 
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
        - python test.py



pipelines:
  default:
    - step: # non-parallel step
        name: Build
        script:
          - ./build.sh
    - parallel: # these 2 steps will run in parallel
        - step:
            name: Integration 1
            script:
              - ./integration-tests.sh --batch 1
        - step:
            name: Integration 2
            script:
              - ./integration-tests.sh --batch 2
    - step:          # non-parallel step
        script:
          - ./deploy.sh
```

etc.

It seems in case of `parallel` absence the steps/scripts/instructions goes sequentially. So how a bitbucket pipeline knows the previous step is over an it's time to start the next one?

Comment: the pipeline is waiting for all steps to finished in `parallel` before executing the next step

Comment: how does pipeline know the steps in `parallel` are finished?

Comment: when all script executions are successfully finished.

Comment: the scripts do not report to pipeline they are finished. Scripts don't even know they are running inside pipeline. Scripts just print out to console ( if any) some words like `completed successfully` ( but not mandatory exact these words) + put artifacts or reports ( if any) somewhere. But pipeline doesn't have eyes to read  console unlike humans, so how pipeline knows it?

Comment: all programms should finish with an exit code. 0 is for failing and >0 for success.

Comment: hmm, I've never read this rule is mandatory for all programs ))) what if some script doesn't return anything? Does it mean the script is not applicable for bitbucket pipelines? Can you point to this requirement in bitbucket's docs?

Comment: im sorry. 0 is success. Thats normal behavoir in linux. You can also use an exit code in pyton with `sys.exit`

Comment: so does it mean if I write a script returns nothing it's not applicable for bitbucket pipelines? Can you point to this requirement in bitbucket's docs?